# recursively add Models to Scout Laravel

Tags: laravel, algolia, laravel-scout

I have three tables

```
 "Aktes" has Many "lvs"
 "lvs" has Many "Ms"
 "Ms"
```

And i want to be able to search Ms->attribute in AkteController.

I added lvs to Searchable Array:

```
//Model Akte

public function toSearchableArray()
{
    $arr = $this->toArray();
    $arr['lvs'] = $this->lvs()->toSearchableArray();
    return $arr;
}
```

Is it possible to add lvs.M to Akte SeachableArray?

Comment: My friend please. If your project is in development, I suggest to have names to your tables, columns and consequently, Models, that make sense. Trust me, it will help you a lot in development.I had to look `toSearchableArray` up and I've found https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/scout#configuring-searchable-data Looking at what it means, I doubt it is recursive.

Comment: Thanks for your help (: And yes "lv(s)" is actually a name that makes sence hehe